# My Json get cut off when sent with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, angularjs

I'm using angular to save new data on the database, I take the data from my inputs, put it in a object and I convert it to a Json, I send it by POST, but my JSON gets cut off and I have no clue why is it happening.

```
 var myJson = angular.toJson(myObject);
 $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://url/file.php',
   data: {
     'data': myJson
   }
 })
 .success(function (data){
    console.log(data);
  })
```

My `file.php` has a `var_dump($_POST)` in it, and it shows that:

```
[
  {
    "uuid":"56456456456456456456465456"
  },
  {
    "store_name":"",
    "store_email":"",
    "store_facebook":"",
    "contact_name":"John Doe",
    "contact_email":"email@email.com",
    "contact_facebook":"http://localho
```

Comment: `$_POST` wouldn't allow an incomplete object or anything like that ... it seems like the display is just getting cut off

Comment: I'm not send an object, I'm just sending a string.

Comment: Try var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))

Comment: it returns to me that: `string(292) "data=%5B%7B%22uuid%22%3A%2256456456456456456456465456%22%7D%2C%7B%22store_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22store_email%22%3A%22%22%2C%22store_facebook%22%3A%22%22%2C%22contact_name%22%3A%22Fulano%22%2C%22contact_email%22%3A%22fulano%40email.com%22%2C%22contact_facebook%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A" `

Seems to be the same thing, but encoded.

Comment: So, probably your toJson function returns invalid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's http post method sends whatever data it is passed to. You should **check your generated json** data after

`var myJson = angular.toJson(myObject);` using `console.log(myJson);`

and that itself must be cut off.